# How to multiply a group of elements within a vector with a matrix, setting all other elements to zero

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way that selects a group of elements within a vector and multiplies this with a matrix, while setting each other element to zero, then repeating this process for the next group.

for example let

```
a <- c(2:7)
b <- matrix(1:36, byrow = FALSE, nrow = 6)
```

giving

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
[3,]   13   14   15   16   17   18
[4,]   19   20   21   22   23   24
[5,]   25   26   27   28   29   30
[6,]   31   32   33   34   35   36
```

Define a as having three groups:

- element 1 and 2 for group 1
- element 3 and 4 for group 2
- element 5   and 6 for group 3

How can r multiply vector a group 1 with b setting everything else to zero (`2 3 0 0 0 0`), then repeat with group 2 (`0 0 4 5 0 0`) and 3 (`0 0 0 0 6 7`)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include an example of code and you'll be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Also why not just use the three vectors you've created there, why do you start with it in one vector?

Comment: The data set that I'm working with is much larger than the example here, your way would work, but don't know how the code would work

Comment: As for code I might try a loop, c <- for (v in groups) { ...} but I dont know how to iterate over each element

Comment: What are these groups like in the general case? Elements 1,2; 3,4; ...; n-1,n? Or are they given in some form?

Comment: In the general case each group contains 56 elements, so group 1 contains elements a[1:56], group 2 a[57:112], ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result:

```
k <- 2
v <- rep(1:(length(a) %/% k), each = k)
sapply(unique(v), function(n) a[which(v == n)] %*% b[which(v == n), ])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    8   32   72
# [2,]   38   86  150
# [3,]   68  140  228
# [4,]   98  194  306
# [5,]  128  248  384
# [6,]  158  302  462
```

Some explanations. `k` is the number of elements in each group, in your actual case that should be 56. `v` is the vector with a corresponding block number at each coordinate. Then I go over all block numbers `unique(v)`, but instead of creating vectors like `c(2,3,0,0,0,0)` I just take `c(2,3)` *and* only the first two rows of the matrix `b`, which is equivalent to playing with zeros. Also, if the length of `a` is divisible by `k`, you may replace the last line with

```
sapply(unique(v), function(n) a[v == n] %*% b[v == n, ])
```