# How to multiply another group of elements within a vector with a matrix, setting all other elements to zero

Tags: r, matrix, vector

This question is similar to the one I asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206822/how-to-multiply-a-group-of-elements-within-a-vector-with-a-matrix-setting-all-o), but I define the groups here slightly differently.

I am trying to multiply certain elements inside a vector with a matrix, while setting all other elements within the vector to zero, and then repeat the process for the next group. The elements I want to use are n elements apart.

My dataset is again very large, so for illustrative purposes let:

```
a <- c(2:7)
b <- matrix(1:36, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 6)
description <- c("AA1", "AA2", "AA3", "BB1", "BB2", "BB3")
names(a) <- description
```

giving:

```
a

AA1 AA2 AA3 BB1 BB2 BB3 
  2   3   4   5   6   7 

b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
[3,]   13   14   15   16   17   18
[4,]   19   20   21   22   23   24
[5,]   25   26   27   28   29   30
[6,]   31   32   33   34   35   36
```

Define a as having three groups:

- element 1 and 4 for group 1
- element 2 and 5 for group 2
- element 3 and 6 for group 3

So in this example I want to match every element with the same number in the vector and then multiply this with the matrix. So for group 1 the vector would be `(2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0)` group 2 `(0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0)` and group 3 `(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7)`

The vector matrix multiplication (`a %*% b`) for group 1 would give results:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   97  104  111  118  125  132
```

So I was thinking of either matching the numbers inside the vector using the `grepl` code, or somehow tell r to set the two elements between the groups to zero, and then repeat the process for the next group.

What would be the best code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` is the grouping vector c(`1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)` such that all elements corresponding to the same value of the grouping vector belong to the same group. 
 Now `outer(...)` gives a three column matrix `Ind`, each of whose columns is an indicator variable for one group.  For each column of `Ind` perform the indicated calculation in the `sapply`:

```
g <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", names(a)))
Ind <- outer(g, unique(g), `==`)
sapply(1:ncol(Ind), function(i) a %*% (b * Ind[, i]))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   97  171  269
[2,]  104  180  280
[3,]  111  189  291
[4,]  118  198  302
[5,]  125  207  313
[6,]  132  216  324
```

The last line of code could alternately be written:

```
sapply(split(Ind, col(Ind)), function(ind) a[ind] %*% b[ind, ])
```

or

```
sapply(1:ncol(Ind), function(i) a %*% diag(Ind[, i]) %*% b)
```

**Update:** Have revised based on clarification of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help!